# Sort multidimensional list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a below list and I want to sort the 0th index of each row in ascending order. Input is as follow-

```
   [[[41, 34, 45, 55, 63], 'A'],
   [[42, 23, 34, 44, 53], 'B'],
   [[32, 23, 13, 54, 67], 'C'],
   [[23, 82, 23, 63, 34], 'D'],
   [[21, 23, 25, 56, 56], 'E']]]
```

The output should be :-

```
   [[[34, 41, 45, 55, 63], 'A'],
   [[23, 34, 42, 44, 53], 'B'],
   [[13, 23, 32, 54, 67], 'C'],
   [[23, 23, 34, 63, 84], 'D'],
   [[21, 23, 25, 56, 56], 'E']]]
```

I tried to sort by using the sorted() but I am not getting desired output.

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: Additionally, your brackets are not balanced in either list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 a = [[[41, 34, 45, 55, 63], 'A'],
   [[42, 23, 34, 44, 53], 'B'],
   [[32, 23, 13, 54, 67], 'C'],
   [[23, 82, 23, 63, 34], 'D'],
   [[21, 23, 25, 56, 56], 'E']]

[[sorted(row[0]), row[1]] for row in a]
```